# Writing raw images safely to USB sticks

Tags: linux, permissions, usb, devices, dd

Trying lots of different Linux distributions on all kinds of hardware, I find myself typing commands like this quite often:

```
sudo dd if=xubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdc bs=10240
```

Needless to say, sooner or later I will mistype the destination and wipe a harddrive instead of the intended USB drive. I would like not to use `sudo` every time here.

On my system, a fairly modern Ubuntu, permissions on `/dev/sdc` are like: (when a stick is present):

```
$ ls -al /dev/sdc*
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 32 Apr  6 22:10 /dev/sdc
```

How do I grant my regular user write access to random USB sticks but not other disks present in my system?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you can use UDEV to do what you want. Creating a rules file such as`/etc/udev/rules.d/99-thumbdrives.rules` you'd simply add a rule that will allow either a Unix group or user access to arbitrary USB thumb drives.

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", OWNER="<user>", GROUP="<group>", MODE="0660"
```

Would create the device using the user `<user>` and group `<group>`.

#### Example

1. After adding this line to my system.

   ```
   KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", OWNER="saml", GROUP="saml", MODE="0660"
   ```
2. And reloading my rules:

   ```
   $ sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
   ```
3. If I now insert a thumbdrive into my system, my `/var/log/messages` shows up as follows:

   ```
   $ sudo tail -f /var/log/messages
   Apr 13 11:48:45 greeneggs udisksd[2249]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/saml/HOLA on behalf of uid 1000
   Apr 13 11:51:18 greeneggs udisksd[2249]: Cleaning up mount point /run/media/saml/HOLA (device 8:17 is not mounted)
   Apr 13 11:51:18 greeneggs udisksd[2249]: Unmounted /dev/sdb1 on behalf of uid 1000
   Apr 13 11:51:18 greeneggs kernel: [171038.843969] sdb: detected capacity change from 32768000 to 0
   Apr 13 11:51:39 greeneggs kernel: [171058.964358] usb 2-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 15
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs kernel: [171066.053922] usb 2-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 16 using ehci-pci
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs kernel: [171066.134401] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=9380
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs kernel: [171066.134407] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs kernel: [171066.134410] usb 2-1.2: Product: USBDrive
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs kernel: [171066.134412] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: JMTek
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs kernel: [171066.135470] usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs kernel: [171066.136121] scsi17 : usb-storage 2-1.2:1.0
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 16: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2"
   Apr 13 11:51:46 greeneggs mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 16 was not an MTP device
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.139462] scsi 17:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMTek    USBDrive         7.77 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.140251] sd 17:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.142105] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] 64000 512-byte logical blocks: (32.7 MB/31.2 MiB)
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.144236] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.145988] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.145998] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.153721] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.153728] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.159028]  sdb: sdb1
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.164760] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.164768] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.164775] sd 17:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs kernel: [171067.635474] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
   Apr 13 11:51:47 greeneggs udisksd[2249]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at /run/media/saml/HOLA on behalf of uid 1000
   ```
4. Now checking out the device files under `/dev` shows the following:

   ```
   $ ls -l /dev/sd*
   brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  0 Apr 13 09:17 /dev/sda
   brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  1 Apr 13 09:17 /dev/sda1
   brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8,  2 Apr 13 09:17 /dev/sda2
   brw-rw----. 1 saml saml 8, 16 Apr 13 11:51 /dev/sdb
   brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 17 Apr 13 11:51 /dev/sdb1
   ```

So it would seem to have worked.

#### Being more explicit

The above will work but will likely have these rules getting applied to every block device which isn't quite what we want. To narrow its focus a bit you can use `ATTRS{..}==...` attribute rules to restrict the application to specific hardware. In my case I only want it to be applied to a single USB thumbdrive.

#### Step #1 - uniquely id device

So to start we can use this command once we've mounted the particular thumb drive so that we can use `udevadm` to scrutinize it, groping it for its particular attributes.

Here I'm focusing on looking at the "manufacturer" and "product" attributes.

```
$ udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)|grep -iE "manufacturer|product"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="JMTek"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="9380"
    ATTRS{product}=="USBDrive"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0020"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 3.13.7-100.fc19.x86_64 ehci_hcd"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0002"
    ATTRS{product}=="EHCI Host Controller"
```

**NOTE:** `ATTRS{..}==..` attributes are attributes to parent devices in the hierarchy of where this device's device file is ultimately deriving from. So in our case the block device being added, `/dev/sdb` is coming from a USB parent device, so we're looking for this parent's attributes, `ATTRS{manufacturer}=...`, for example.

So in this example I'm selecting the manufacturer "JMTek" and the product "USBDrive".

#### Step #2 - modify .rules flie

So with these additional bits in hand let's add them to our original `.rules` file.

```
KERNEL=="sd*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{DEVTYPE}=="disk", ATTRS{manufacturer}=="JMTek", ATTRS{product}=="USBDrive", OWNER="saml", GROUP="saml", MODE="0660"
```

#### Step #3 - Trying it out

Now when we reload our rules and unmount/remove/reinsert our USB thumbdrive again we get this rule:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdb*
brw-rw----. 1 saml saml 8, 16 Apr 13 12:29 /dev/sdb
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 17 Apr 13 12:29 /dev/sdb1
```

However if I insert a completely different device:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sdb*
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 16 Apr 13 12:41 /dev/sdb
brw-rw----. 1 root disk 8, 17 Apr 13 12:41 /dev/sdb1
```

#### References

- [ArchLinux Wiki UDEV Topic](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udev)

Comment: This, already, is the most correct answer. You don't often disappoint, slm.

Comment: Shouldn't you use the block subsystem? If i am not mistaken, this rule will match the /dev/usb/xxx/yyy device instead of /dev/sdc. ATTRS rather than ATTR should match parent devices (i.e. block).

Comment: @Lekensteyn - thanks it wasn't quite working for me originally and I couldn't figure out why. With your big clue and moving the rule to the end (`99-...`) I'm now able to actually show a real demo that works. Thanks again for the guidance!

Comment: I had to fight a little but I ended up using `SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", GROUP="mogul"` Which I read as "any USB disk will be in group mogul". using a 99 rule helped too

Comment: @mogul - yes it's a bit of trial and error getting things square 8-)

Comment: At my end I get nothing :- 

`[$] udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)|grep -iE "manufacturer|product"' `  
`[$]` . Any ideas ?

Comment: @shirish - ask this as a new Q and reference this one. Also take the grep out for starters, do you get any output from udevinfo and/or udevadm? It's likely that you do not have a /dev/sdb device.