# figuring out the e "manufacturer" and "product" attributes using udev for pendrive

Tags: debian, usb, udev

I saw [Writing raw images safely to USB sticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124540/writing-raw-images-safely-to-usb-sticks/124554?noredirect=1#comment361139_124554)

On Debian though, get nada from that command :-

```
[$] udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)|grep -iE "manufacturer|product"  
[$]
```

I was asked to put it up as a new question hence doing just that :-

I do get some output from udevadm if I use monitor command :-

```
[$] udevadm monitor                                                                                                                
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[3684.776590] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/bsg/4:0:0:0 (bsg)
KERNEL[3684.777597] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[3684.777635] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_device/4:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[3684.777658] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[3684.777838] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
KERNEL[3684.782360] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
KERNEL[3684.782727] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[3684.782760] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[3684.782988] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
KERNEL[3684.783019] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [3684.783049] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/bsg/4:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [3684.784068] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_disk/4:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
UDEV  [3684.785019] remove   /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [3684.787027] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [3684.791681] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
UDEV  [3684.791719] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/scsi_device/4:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [3684.792728] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
UDEV  [3684.795562] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [3684.798166] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0/4:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [3684.800061] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/target4:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[3684.808192] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/scsi_host/host4 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[3684.808231] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4 (scsi)
KERNEL[3684.808519] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3684.808707] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8 (usb)
UDEV  [3684.809582] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4/scsi_host/host4 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [3684.810490] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host4 (scsi)
UDEV  [3684.811610] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3684.813368] remove   /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8 (usb)
KERNEL[3690.682615] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8 (usb)
KERNEL[3690.683475] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[3690.683743] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5 (scsi)
KERNEL[3690.683944] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/scsi_host/host5 (scsi_host)
UDEV  [3690.692470] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8 (usb)
UDEV  [3690.699536] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [3690.701644] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5 (scsi)
UDEV  [3690.708123] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/scsi_host/host5 (scsi_host)
KERNEL[3691.694749] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[3691.694829] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[3691.694902] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/scsi_disk/5:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[3691.694961] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/scsi_device/5:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
KERNEL[3691.695201] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
KERNEL[3691.695321] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/bsg/5:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [3691.697351] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0 (scsi)
KERNEL[3691.697770] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [3691.702172] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0 (scsi)
UDEV  [3691.705059] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/scsi_disk/5:0:0:0 (scsi_disk)
KERNEL[3691.705443] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
KERNEL[3691.705469] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
KERNEL[3691.705485] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
UDEV  [3691.710056] add      /devices/virtual/bdi/8:16 (bdi)
UDEV  [3691.712737] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/bsg/5:0:0:0 (bsg)
UDEV  [3691.713573] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/scsi_device/5:0:0:0 (scsi_device)
UDEV  [3691.714949] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/scsi_generic/sg2 (scsi_generic)
UDEV  [3692.356460] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb (block)
UDEV  [3692.392059] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb2 (block)
UDEV  [3692.440775] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1 (block)
```

Also lsblk confirms there is something at sdb, see :-

```
[$] lsblk                                                                                                                          
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  48.8G  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
├─sda5   8:5    0  48.8G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0 186.3G  0 part /
├─sda7   8:7    0  93.1G  0 part /home
├─sda8   8:8    0 549.5G  0 part /data
└─sda9   8:9    0     5G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   1   247M  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   1   416K  0 part 
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I also get output here as well :-

```
[$] ls -l /dev/sdb*                                                                                                                
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Jun 30 15:49 /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 17 Jun 30 15:49 /dev/sdb1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 18 Jun 30 15:49 /dev/sdb2
```

Look forward to learning how to get the manufacturer and product info. or maybe it got written over or something.

Part of the command does do something :-

```
[$] udevadm info -a -p $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/sdb)                                                                         

Udevadm info starts with the device specified by the devpath and then
walks up the chain of parent devices. It prints for every device
found, all possible attributes in the udev rules key format.
A rule to match, can be composed by the attributes of the device
and the attributes from one single parent device.

  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0/block/sdb':
    KERNEL=="sdb"
    SUBSYSTEM=="block"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0/5:0:0:0':
    KERNELS=="5:0:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS=="sd"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5/target5:0:0':
    KERNELS=="target5:0:0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0/host5':
    KERNELS=="host5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="scsi"
    DRIVERS==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8/5-8:1.0':
    KERNELS=="5-8:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb-storage"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5/5-8':
    KERNELS=="5-8"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb5':
    KERNELS=="usb5"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:1d.7"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ehci-pci"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

but the latter part gives nothing, the `grep -iE "manufacturer|product"` part :(

Am able to get it on lsusb :-

```
[$] lsusb                                                                                                                           
Bus 005 Device 007: ID 058f:6387 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Drive
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Was able to get the required output via lsscsi i.e. manufacturer/product i.e. Jetflash and the model number. Does anybody know more Alcor Micro Corporation ?

More interestingly though, why didn't that command work ?

Comment: You can check `lsscsi` or `Debian` has utility [discover](http://manpages.debian.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?sektion=1&query=discover&apropos=0&manpath=sid&locale=en).

Comment: Does it show up with `lsusb` ?